# Ethernet Wall Jack not working - Unique pre-wiring work on it

Tags: networking, ethernet

We moved into our house about a year ago and so all the ethernet wall ports were pre-wired.  I only got to it now, but the two wall jacks to the left of our house do not work.  I opened up the wall jack in our home office which is on the left side of the house and saw it was set up like this:

[Previous set up of the wires](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCnBb.jpg)

This picture has it where the Orange/Orange Stripe and the Green/Green Stripe cables were connected to the Etherenet port and the blue/blue striped cables were connected to the phone line port.  The Brown/Brown Striped cords weren't connected anywhere.

I used an older posting here and reconnected all the cords to the b sides based on their color coded icons as shown below:
[Revised Set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P23Fj.jpg)

[2nd angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxjb6.jpg)

After I did this, the port still doesn't work.  Based on these pictures, can you assist with determining if the issue was the way I connected it or could it be the cable itself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check the other end of the cable?

Comment: Hi Ignacio, regarding the other end of the cable, I think they all go into a centralized switch where there's about a dozen ethernet cables connected to it.  Unfortunately, none of the cables were labeled as to which one goes where.  is there a way to test the switch where all the cables connect to?

Comment: I recommend getting a cable tracer so that you can get things done correctly.

Comment: Re-wiring only one side without knowing what's on the other side will rarely work ... it looks like they used a single cable to carry both the phone and a 100-MBit two-pair Ethernet connection. Which is perfectly fine, provided the other side is wired up correctly, and of course it's not a 1-Gbit connection (four pairs).

Comment: You can use a "cat5" cable tester to find the other end.  Google "cat 5 cable tester".  They can be had including shipping for under $10.  They check for conductivity (vs quality of connection) and will make it easy to determine which cable goes where.

Answer (score 0):

The common UTP (Unshielded Twisted Pair) cable used for Ethernet consists of four pairs.  However, for the original 10 megabit, and later 100 megabit speeds of Ethernet, only two of the pairs were used.  A common hack was to take the two unused pairs and use them for something else.  This violated the specification, but happened to work in many cases.  In this case, it looks like it was used to run a phone line and Ethernet on one cable.

Later versions of Ethernet (1000 megabit, AKA gigabit, and up) require all four pairs.  Most of the PoE (power-over-Ethernet) variants need all four pairs, too.

Fixing the cable run will require finding the other end of the cable and fixing the termination at that end, too.  They have to match.

To find the other end of a mystery cable, you can use a cable tracing toolkit, which consists of a tone generator and a probe.  The tone generator goes at the known end.  It puts an electrical signal (typically a beeping pattern) on the wire.  The probe is an antenna, speaker, and amplifier.  Put the probe near the same cable, and you hear the beeping noise.  Cheap kits go for about $30 US; better ones go for up to $100 US or so.  For casual use, a cheap kit is usually adequate.

Alternatively, you can find the wiring hub, find all the unused cables/ports, and connect a continuity tester to each cable, one at a time, with the far end shorted.